# Get first child node in XSLT using local-name()

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xslt-1.0, xalan

Assume we have this simple xml ...

```
 <books>   
    <book>
       <author/>
       <title/>
    </book>
    <book>
       <author/>
       <title/>
    </book>
 </books>
```

I'm using this xpath to get the elements of the first book instance.

```
//books[1]/*
```

Returns

```
<author/>
<title/>
```

And that works fine, but I have to get it working using local-name(). I've tried the following but none of these work...

```
//*[local-name()='books']/*
```

this returns repeating author and title elements, not good, I only need them from the first child

```
//*[local-name()='books'][0]/*
```

this does not return anything

Basically, I want to create a CSV file, so the first line in the output will be a header listing the book attribute names followed by the arbitrary data values. I only need to get the header part working.

```
author,title
john,The End is Near
sally,Looking for Answers
```

Comment: Your query `//books[1]/*` should return two book elements, not an author and a title element. So there is some confusion somewhere.

Comment: Nope, it returns just the first one with my Xalan 1.0 XSLT transformer

Comment: Yeah, that was my bad in the OP, I am using [1]-based, thx for the info

Comment: @RaffiM: Are you aware of the fact that you have accepted a generally incorrect answer?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The path expression you say works for you

```
//books[1]/*
```

generates a list of all child nodes of the first (and only in this case) occurrence of any <books> node. Because, in your data, the only occurrence of <books> is at the root, it is the same as

```
/books/*
```

which returns two <book> nodes, and so you are wrong to say that it returns only one node.

It is hard to know what you need, as if you are always applying `local-name` to the root node then you do not need to know its name and can access it with just `/*`, so you would want simply

```
/*/*[1]
```

However to access the first child node of a <books> node anywhere in the document you would write

```
//*[local-name()='books']/*[1]
```

You should be careful to confine your context as much as possible, as starting the XPath expression with `//` will force a search of the entire document, which is pointless and time-consuming if the node in question is always at the root.

Comment: See my edits above int he original post for more details on what I'm trying to accomplish, sorry for the lack of additional detail. I tried using /*/*[1], it's printing "author,title" twice, i just need it to print once.

Answer (score 13):

**This is a FAQ** -- the XPath `[]` operator has higher precedence (priority) than the `//` pseudo-operator.

So:

```
//someElemName[1]
```

selects every element named `someElemName` that is the first child of its parent -- and, depending on the XML document, there can be more than one such elements.

To change this, one must use brackets.

**Use**:

```
(//*[local-name() = 'book'])[1]/*
```

**Also note**: In XPath positions are 1-based, not 0-based.

**XSLT-based verification:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:copy-of select=
  "(//*[local-name() = 'book'])[1]/*"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this transformation is applied on the following XML document**:

```
<books>
    <book num="1">
        <author num="1"/>
        <title num="1"/>
    </book>
    <book num="2">
        <author num="2"/>
        <title num="2"/>
    </book>
</books>
```

**the wanted nodes are selected and copied to the output**:

```
<author num="1"/>
<title num="1"/>
```

Comment: @RaffiM: Was my answer useful to you?

Answer (score 0):

I have to meet same concerns. I solved as follows:

```
//*[local-name()='MYNODENAME' and position()=X]
```

Have a nice day.