# Java XPathExpression for Child Element Using Parent Element As XPath Parameter

Tags: java, xml, xslt, xpath, xslt-1.0

For the following xml:

```
<books>   
    <book>
       <author>Peter</author>
       <title>Tales from Somewhere</title>
       <data>
          <version>1</version>
       </data>
    </book>
    <book>
       <author>Paul</author>
       <title>Tales from Nowhere</title>
       <data>
          <version>2</version>
       </data>
    </book>
 </books>
```

How can I get the `<version>` value of the book author 'Paul' above, using this type of notation for building a Java XPathExpression:

```
//*[local-name()='books']/*
```

?

I used the following question as a reference:
[Get first child node in XSLT using local-name()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8058308/get-first-child-node-in-xslt-using-local-name)

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [XPath for Child Element Using Parent Element As XPath Parameter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21034950/xpath-for-child-element-using-parent-element-as-xpath-parameter)

Comment: You submitted it twice it seems.

Comment: Thanks.  Duplicate deleted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This XPath will get the version of a book where there is at an `author` element with the value "Paul":

```
//book[author="Paul"]/data/version
```

When run against this XML:

```
<books> 
  <book> 
    <author>Peter</author>  
    <title>Tales from Somewhere</title>  
    <data> 
      <version>1</version> 
    </data> 
  </book>  
  <book> 
    <author>Paul</author>  
    <title>Tales from Nowhere</title>  
    <data> 
      <version>2</version> 
    </data> 
  </book> 
  <book> 
    <author>Peter</author>  
    <author>Paul</author>  
    <title>How to write a book with a friend</title>  
    <data> 
      <version>7</version> 
    </data> 
  </book> 
</books>
```

You get this result:

```
<version>1</version>
<version>7</version>
```

Comment: Thanks.  That is the XPath, which is great. Now I am looking for the expression used to build a Java XPathExpression with, based on this XPath (apologies for not specifying that earlier).

Comment: I don't do the java. It might be best asking a fresh question for that.

Comment: Was not expecting your answer to be able to compile into an XPathExpression but it did. Cheers